# How to get pytz timezone from common abbreviation (PST, EST, etc.)?

Tags: python, pytz

This is a similar question as [How to get the common name for a pytz timezone eg. EST/EDT for America/New_York](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946499/how-to-get-the-common-name-for-a-pytz-timezone-eg-est-edt-for-america-new-york) , except I want to be able to just get a timezone from "PST" from pytz. such as `tz = timezone("PST")` Is this something like this possible with pytz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up just manually making a dictionary that mapped abbreviations to timezone names. For example, `'PST' : 'America/Los_Angeles'` would be an entry (as would PDT for the daylight savings abbreviation).

Comment: Bad idea.  Time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous.  For example, there are 5 different meanings of "CST".  [See Wikipedia's list of abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations).

Comment: @MattJohnson thank you, this is helpful. I always thought it's unique!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using strptime with the %Z format code?  I've never done it myself, but at least in theory you should be able to put in the tz code there and it should get translated into a tzinfo (embedded in the datetime/time object)

Comment: this would not resolve my issue. that would only get a constant offset. For example, PST and PDT would be translated to different offsets by %Z, but the datetime still not would be aware of the change to/from daylight savings time.