# Get timezone object using UTC offset or timezone abbreviation

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pytz

So, I am facing a problem in timezone conversion. I know that in pytz library, if you pass timezone name, you will get timezone object. Ex. timezone('Asia/Kolkata'). But, is there any way that we can retrieve the timezone using UTC offset or timezone abbreviation. 
1. If I pass some_func('UTC+5:30') gives me 'Asia/Kolkata' or timezone object.
2. If I pass some_func('IST') it gives me 'Asia/Kolkata' or timezone object.

Comment: You want to remove 'UTC+5:30' ?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9938035/2689986

Comment: @ashish I don't want to keep any manual mapping

Comment: @dl.meteo : No, I don't want to remove UTC+5:30, I want to get timezone using this offset.