# Convert non-UTC time string with timezone abbreviation into UTC time in python, while accounting for daylight savings

Tags: python, utc, dst, pytz, python-dateutil

I am having a hard time converting a string representation of non-UTC times to UTC due to the timezone abbreviation.

**(update: it seems that the [timezone abbreviations may not be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946499/how-to-get-the-common-name-for-a-pytz-timezone-eg-est-edt-for-america-new-york?rq=1). if so, perhaps i should also be trying to take this into account.**)

I've been trying to look for a way around this using datetutil and pytz, but haven't had any luck.

Suggestions or workaround would be appreciated.

```
string = "Jun 20, 4:00PM EDT"
```

**I'd like to convert that into UTC time, accounting for daylight savings when appropriate.**

**UPDATE:** Found some references that may help more experienced users answer the Q.

Essentially, I would imagine part of the solution doing the reverse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946499/how-to-get-the-common-name-for-a-pytz-timezone-eg-est-edt-for-america-new-york?rq=1).

**FINAL UPDATE (IMPORTANT)**

Taken from the [dateutil docs examples](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-587bd3efc48f897f55c179abc520a34330ee0a62).

**Some simple examples based on the date command, using the TZOFFSET dictionary to provide the BRST timezone offset.**

> > > parse("Thu Sep 25 10:36:28 BRST 2003", tzinfos=TZOFFSETS)
> > >       datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 36, 28,
> > >                         tzinfo=tzoffset('BRST', -10800))
> > >
> > > parse("2003 10:36:28 BRST 25 Sep Thu", tzinfos=TZOFFSETS)
> > >       datetime.datetime(2003, 9, 25, 10, 36, 28,
> > >                         tzinfo=tzoffset('BRST', -10800))

**Combine this with a library [such as found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python/4766400#4766400) and you will have a solution to this problem.**

Comment: What value should be used for the year? Current?

Comment: @beargle - yes. i would assume current for all of these outputs.

Comment: Yes, timezone abbreviations aren't unique across the world. Can you assume a country?

Comment: Take a look at @Nas Banov's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703546/parsing-date-time-string-with-timezone-abbreviated-name-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [Nas Banov's excellent dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766400/366335) mapping timezone abbreviations to UTC offset:

```
import dateutil
import pytz

# timezone dictionary built here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766400/366335
# tzd = {...}

string = 'Jun 20, 4:00PM EDT'
date = dateutil.parser.parse(string, tzinfos=tzd).astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: I was just about to come back with an update about the libraries.