# linux convert time(for different timezones) to UTC

Tags: c, linux, gcc, timezone

Is there a way, in linux, to programmatically get UTC time for a given time string like

```
Tue Dec  14 10:30:23 PST 2012
Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 EST 2013
```

to a UTC time, irrespective of( and without changing) local time zone settings?

Comment: what I personally want to know what is the difference between a normal time n UTC time?

Comment: is it time in your local timezone? In general the abbreviations such as PST, EST are not enough to find the timezone unambiguously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date -u -d "Tue Dec 14 10:30:23 PST 2012"` reports `Fri Dec 14 18:30:23 UTC 2012`. The discrepancy is because Dec 14 2012 is in fact a Friday, not a Tuesday. It probably works better with valid input...

Comment: `date` works for the string with PST by accident (timezones that correspond to `PST` name have the same utc offset for the given date). But [the time string with EST is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13713813/4279).

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: the result with the recent tz database is different: [EST yields the same utc offset for a given date](http://ideone.com/ZIYkvl) (compare with [the previous result](http://ideone.com/YPbXEG)). Though it does not affect the general conclusion that different timezones may use the same abbreviation and therefore the same abbreviation may correspond to different utc offsets. See [Parsing date/time string with timezone abbreviated name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1703546/4279)

---

Abbreviated timezone names such as EST may be ambiguous.

#### Example

```
#!/bin/sh
for tz in Australia/Brisbane Australia/Sydney America/New_York
do date -u -d"TZ=\":$tz\" Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 EST 2013"
done
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/YPbXEG)

```
Fri Jan  4 16:30:23 UTC 2013
Fri Jan  4 00:30:23 UTC 2013
Fri Jan  4 16:30:23 UTC 2013
```

Two things:

- the date string may be interpreted as different moments in time depending on the timezone used
- `date` silently ignores `Australia/Brisbane` timezone that should be `UTC+10` i.e., `date` interprets `EST` as belonging to a different timezone. Without `EST` it produces correct time:

  ```
    $ date -u -d 'TZ=":Australia/Brisbane" Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 2013'
    Fri Jan  4 01:30:23 UTC 2013
  ```

To find all possible UTC times for given time and timezone abbreviation e.g., for `'Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 EST 2013'`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ sudo apt-get install python-tz
            # or if you can't install system-wide
            # $ pip install --user pytz

## Tue Dec  14 10:30:23 PST 2012
#naive_dt, tzname = datetime(2012, 12, 14, 10, 30, 23), 'PST'
## -> Fri Dec 14 18:30:23 2012 UTC

# Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 EST 2013
naive_dt, tzname = datetime(2013, 1, 4, 11, 30, 23), 'EST'
# Fri Jan  4 01:30:23 2013 UTC
# Fri Jan  4 00:30:23 2013 UTC
# Fri Jan  4 16:30:23 2013 UTC
# ambiguous
 
utc_times = defaultdict(list)
for zone in pytz.all_timezones:
    dt = pytz.timezone(zone).localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None)
    if dt.tzname() == tzname: # same timezone abbreviation
        utc_times[dt.astimezone(pytz.utc)].append(zone)

for utc_dt, timezones in utc_times.items():
    print("%s:\n\t%s" % (utc_dt.strftime('%c %Z'), '\n\t'.join(timezones)))
```

#### Output

All `Tue Jan  4 11:30:23 EST 2013` interpretations as UTC with corresponding timezone names:

```
Fri Jan  4 01:30:23 2013 UTC:
    Australia/Brisbane
    Australia/Lindeman
    Australia/Queensland
Fri Jan  4 00:30:23 2013 UTC:
    Australia/ACT
    Australia/Canberra
    Australia/Currie
    Australia/Hobart
    Australia/Melbourne
    Australia/NSW
    Australia/Sydney
    Australia/Tasmania
    Australia/Victoria
Fri Jan  4 16:30:23 2013 UTC:
    America/Atikokan
    America/Cayman
    America/Coral_Harbour
    America/Detroit
    ...
    America/New_York
    ...
    America/Toronto
    Canada/Eastern
    EST
    EST5EDT
    Jamaica
    US/East-Indiana
    US/Eastern
    US/Michigan
```