# Python Convert String to Local DateTime to UTC DateTime

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, pytz, python-dateutil

Really stuck here. I've had a look at various answers but zone of them seem to work (Python2.7)

I've got a string `fileGenTime`, representing a time/date. I need to parse it into a date/time and then convert it into UTC. I've tried using 'pytz' and then 'dateutil' but I'm not sure why it won't work.... Here's my attempt...

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

fileGenTime = 'Thu Jan  2 19:23:34 EST 2014'
fileGenTime = fileGenTime.replace('  ',' ') #double spaces...
wday, month, day, time, zone, year = fileGenTime.split(' ')
hour, minute, second = time.split(':')

localGenTime = datetime.strptime(day +' '+ month +' '+ year
 +' '+ hour +' '+ minute +' '+ second, '%d %b %Y %H %M %S')
```

I had initially tried including the `zone` in this last line and using `%Z` in the format arg... Now I'm trying to convert the local time into one with a time zone, and then use `astimezone` to convert it to UTC.

```
localZone = tz.gettz(zone)
localGenTime = localGenTime.replace(tzinfo = localZone)

normalisedTimezone = tz.gettz('UTC')
normalisedGenTime = localGenTime.astimezone(normalisedTimezone)
```

The error message I'm getting says....
"ValueError: month must be in 1..12"....eh?

I'm pulling my hair out! Any help would be appreciated!

Full traceback here....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg\dateutil\tzwin.py", line 32, in utcoffset
    if self._isdst(dt):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg\dateutil\tzwin.py", line 67, in _isdst
    self._dstweeknumber)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-1.5-py2.7.egg\dateutil\tzwin.py", line 166, in picknthweekday
    first = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1, hour, minute)
ValueError: month must be in 1..12
```

Comment: Could you add the full traceback?

Comment: Edited to include traceback Nigel, thanks

Comment: On my machine it runs ok. Your dateutil version is quite old. Can you try it with a newer version?

Comment: note: [`EST` timezone abbriviation is ambigous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13713813/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Windows with an old version of `dateutil` and you've hit [this dateutil bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dateutil/+bug/1010050).

Solutions (I've tried both, both worked):

1. Upgrade dateutile from version 1.5 to version 2.2
2. If for some reason you can't upgrade then you can delete files `Lib/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.py` and `Lib/site-packages/dateutil/tzwin.pyc`. But that's pure evil. I would go with the option #1.