# Convert datetime to UTC to store in DateTimeField Django

Tags: django, pytz

I have an accounts page which lets you put in a DateTime as follows:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="date" autocomplete="off" required>
<input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Time" name="time" autocomplete="off" required>
```

When the form is submitted, I want to convert them from `PST` (which is what they were entered in) to `UTC` (what my backend is in). How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848628/python-convert-pst-time-to-utc-isoformat adapt this to your view

Comment: Does the ```dataparser``` work with all ```pytz``` timezones?

Comment: I dont know, I just searched for a duplicate question... and you particularly asked for PST/UTC^^