# Python: All possible Timezone Abbreviations for given Timezone Name (and vise versa)

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

Using `pytz`, I know how to get a listing a *Timezone names*, but I would like to get *all* possible *Timezone abbreviations* for each Timezone name:

```
import pytz
list(pytz.common_timezones)
['Africa/Abidjan', 'Africa/Accra', 'Africa/Addis_Ababa',...]
```

What I am looking for is given any *Timezone abbreviation*, example **PST** or **PDT**, ignoring current datetime (e.g. now), return the all possible *Timezone name*, in this case a list that would include **America/Los_Angeles**.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like unutbu's answer, which led me to the answer that worked for me.  I have the locale of the user, so I found that I can use that to remove the ambiguity between time zone abbreviations.

In other words, this fixes the problem with the following:

```
In [242]: 'Asia/Shanghai' in tzones['CST']
Out[242]: True

In [243]: 'US/Central' in tzones['CST']
Out[243]: True
```

This function requires a two letter country code:

```
def GetTimeZoneName(timezone, country_code):

    #see if it's already a valid time zone name
    if timezone in pytz.all_timezones:
        return timezone

    #if it's a number value, then use the Etc/GMT code
    try:
        offset = int(timezone)
        if offset > 0:
            offset = '+' + str(offset)
        else:
            offset = str(offset)
        return 'Etc/GMT' + offset
    except ValueError:
        pass

    #look up the abbreviation
    country_tzones = None
    try:
        country_tzones = pytz.country_timezones[country_code]
    except:
        pass

    set_zones = set()
    if country_tzones is not None and len(country_tzones) > 0:
        for name in country_tzones:
            tzone = pytz.timezone(name)
            for utcoffset, dstoffset, tzabbrev in getattr(tzone, '_transition_info', [[None, None, datetime.datetime.now(tzone).tzname()]]):
                if tzabbrev.upper() == timezone.upper():
                    set_zones.add(name)

        if len(set_zones) > 0:
            return min(set_zones, key=len)

        # none matched, at least pick one in the right country
        return min(country_tzones, key=len)


    #invalid country, just try to match the timezone abbreviation to any time zone
    for name in pytz.all_timezones:
        tzone = pytz.timezone(name)
        for utcoffset, dstoffset, tzabbrev in getattr(tzone, '_transition_info', [[None, None, datetime.datetime.now(tzone).tzname()]]):
            if tzabbrev.upper() == timezone.upper():
                set_zones.add(name)

    return min(set_zones, key=len)
```

This returns the correct time zones for CST:

```
>>> GetTimeZoneName('CST','CN')
'Asia/Shanghai'

>>> GetTimeZoneName('CST','US')
'America/Detroit'
```

Comment: Your example raised an interesting problem, is the `date +%Z` command returned value will be both CST, if called in a Shanghai machine and in a Detroit machine ?

Comment: @intijk I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.  I am not using a date +%Z time.  I get the abbreviated time zone from the device.  I get "CST" from both a Shanghai machine and a Detroit machine.  I'm trying to use this to get the correct pytz time zone.

Comment: I believe Detroit is in eastern time and not central.

Answer (score 10):

Since you wish to ignore the current datetime, it sounds like you want to find
any timezone which ever used the given abbreviation at **any time in the
past**. That information is in the Olson database and accessible through
pytz. However, pytz stores this information in the *private* attribute,
`tzone._transition_info`:

```
import collections
import datetime as DT
import pytz

tzones = collections.defaultdict(set)
abbrevs = collections.defaultdict(set)

for name in pytz.all_timezones:
    tzone = pytz.timezone(name)
    for utcoffset, dstoffset, tzabbrev in getattr(
            tzone, '_transition_info', [[None, None, DT.datetime.now(tzone).tzname()]]):
        tzones[tzabbrev].add(name)
        abbrevs[name].add(tzabbrev)
```

The reason for the third (default) argument to `gettattr` is to handle a few
timezones, such as `Africa/Bujumbura`, which never had any transitions. So the
abbreviation in these cases is the current abbreviation.

---

```
In [94]: tzones['PST']
Out[94]: 
{'America/Bahia_Banderas',
 'America/Boise',
 'America/Creston',
 'America/Dawson',
 'America/Dawson_Creek',
 'America/Ensenada',
 'America/Hermosillo',
 'America/Inuvik',
 'America/Juneau',
 'America/Los_Angeles',
 'America/Mazatlan',
 'America/Metlakatla',
 'America/Santa_Isabel',
 'America/Sitka',
 'America/Tijuana',
 'America/Vancouver',
 'America/Whitehorse',
 'Canada/Pacific',
 'Canada/Yukon',
 'Mexico/BajaNorte',
 'Mexico/BajaSur',
 'PST8PDT',
 'Pacific/Pitcairn',
 'US/Pacific',
 'US/Pacific-New'}
```

---

```
In [95]: tzones['PDT']
Out[95]: 
{'America/Boise',
 'America/Dawson',
 'America/Dawson_Creek',
 'America/Ensenada',
 'America/Juneau',
 'America/Los_Angeles',
 'America/Metlakatla',
 'America/Santa_Isabel',
 'America/Sitka',
 'America/Tijuana',
 'America/Vancouver',
 'America/Whitehorse',
 'Canada/Pacific',
 'Canada/Yukon',
 'Mexico/BajaNorte',
 'PST8PDT',
 'US/Pacific',
 'US/Pacific-New'}
```

---

```
In [97]: abbrevs['America/Los_Angeles']
Out[97]: {'LMT', 'PDT', 'PPT', 'PST', 'PWT'}
```

---

As [Paul points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067621/python-all-possible-timezone-abbreviations-for-given-timezone-name-and-vise-ve/36068039?noredirect=1#comment59827019_36068039), note that timezone abbreviations are ambiguous -- they do not necessarily map to timezones with the same utcoffset. For example, both `Asia/Shanghai` and `US/Central` use the `CST` timezone abbreviation.

```
In [242]: 'Asia/Shanghai' in tzones['CST']
Out[242]: True

In [243]: 'US/Central' in tzones['CST']
Out[243]: True
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that these don't necessarily actually all refer to the same zone. Consider that `tzones['CST']` includes `'Cuba'`, `'Asia/Shanghai'` and `'US/Central'`

Comment: This seems to be missing half of all timezones...

`tzones['CSD']` => `set()`

Answer (score 5):

Updating for **py3.9+** (as discussed in [PEP615](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0615/)), the new [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/zoneinfo.html) module may help:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime as dt
from zoneinfo import available_timezones, ZoneInfo

now = dt.utcnow()
tz_key = lambda tz: ZoneInfo(tz).tzname(now)
tz_map = defaultdict(list)

for tz in available_timezones():
    tz_map[tz_key(tz)].append(tz)
tz_map = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in tz_map.items()}
```

e.g., `print(tz_map['PDT'])` would yield: `['America/Ensenada', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Santa_Isabel', 'America/Tijuana', 'America/Vancouver', 'Canada/Pacific', 'Mexico/BajaNorte', 'PST8PDT', 'US/Pacific', 'US/Pacific-New']`

Note: timezone draws from locally-installed timezone data. You can also add the 1st party tzdata library (not in standard lib, but maintained by python's core devs: use `pip install tzdata`).

Comment: note: for a given geographic time zone, different UTC offsets might apply over the course of a year due to DST being active or inactive. Therefore, using `datetime.now()` (no need to use [utcnow](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) btw.) gives you only part of the full picture (thus only a subsection of all the abbreviations).

Answer (score 1):

I did this using the `datetime` module's `strftime` function, as it has a `%Z` format specifier that returns the timezone abbreviation. Here is a `filter` statement that does what you need:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(x)).strftime("%Z") == "PDT", pytz.common_timezones)
['America/Dawson',
'America/Los_Angeles',
'America/Tijuana',
'America/Vancouver',
'America/Whitehorse',
'Canada/Pacific',
'US/Pacific']
```

You can replace `"PDT"` with whatever timezone you need. Remember you'll also need to import `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is using `datetime.now()`, which will only give those timezone names that currently match provide timezone abbreviation. For example, _America/Los_Angeles_ currently matches _PST_ but not _PDT_.

Comment: `>>> list(filter(lambda x: datetime.now(pytz.timezone(x)).strftime("%Z") == "PDT", pytz.common_timezones))
['America/Dawson', 'America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Tijuana', 'America/Vancouver', 'America/Whitehorse', 'Canada/Pacific', 'US/Pacific']`

Comment: `>>> list(filter(lambda x: datetime.now(pytz.timezone(x)).strftime("%Z") == "PST", pytz.common_timezones))
['Pacific/Pitcairn']`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pytz
for tzname in list(pytz.common_timezones):
    print(pytz.timezone(tzname)._tzname)
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946499/how-to-get-the-common-name-for-a-pytz-timezone-eg-est-edt-for-america-new-york)