# How to get EST timezone in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, pytz

I would like to get the EST time with Python. I have the following code:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import time
now_EST = datetime.datetime.today().astimezone(timezone('EST'))
print(now_EST)
```

And the output is:

```
2022-03-29 09:52:55.130992-05:00
```

But when I google the EST time zone, I find out that the time right now is 10:52 am EST, which essentially is the right time.

Why does my code show the 1 hour earlier time compared to the correct one?

Comment: EST is Eastern **Standard** Time. If you want the daylight saving timezone you need to ask for that instead. If you want the currently active timezone, you can do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946499/how-to-get-the-common-name-for-a-pytz-timezone-eg-est-edt-for-america-new-york

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a proper [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to avoid ambiguities of the abbreviations.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

print(datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")))
# 2022-03-29 11:20:30.917144-04:00
```

If you happen to use Python 3.9 or higher, use the built-in [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module to set the time zone (pytz is deprecated):

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

print(datetime.now(ZoneInfo("America/New_York")))
# 2022-03-29 11:20:30.917144-04:00
```

Comment: If I specifically say datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York")), do I always get the actual real time of New York throughout the year no matter daylight saving is active or not?

Comment: @edn yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Daylight Saving Time.  Try "EST5EDT"

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Does EST5EDT always work then independent from daylight saving time changes?

Comment: @edn see [eggert tz / northamerica](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/northamerica): EST5EDT is obsolete, it's just in the IANA tz database for backwards compatibility aka "historical reasons".

Comment: @FObersteiner Thanks a lot clarifying that as well! Specifying the exact location as "America/New_York" is then the correct way to go!