Unexpected difference when subtracting the same time from two different time zones? Python
The total second difference between 2 datetime objects set in different time zones but on the same date does not yield 0.0 in some circumstances.
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
from dateutil import parser
print(datetime.datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern')))
print(datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/Vancouver')))
print((datetime.datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern')) - datetime.datetime.now(timezone('America/Vancouver'))).total_seconds())
print((datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0, timezone('America/Vancouver')) - datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 11, 0, 0, 0, timezone('US/Eastern'))).total_seconds())
print((datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0, timezone('America/Vancouver')) - datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 11, 16, 0, 0, timezone('US/Eastern'))).total_seconds())
print((parser.parse("2011-08-15 08:00:00 UTC-4") - parser.parse("2011-08-15 11:00:00 UTC-7")).total_seconds())

For the third, fourth, and last output of the print statements I would expect them to be all 0.0. I would expect the fifth to be 960.0. However, it seems that when finding the difference of the same date in different time zones using a specific datetime.datetime constructor, it leads to a timezone difference of 3h and 16 minutes between US/Eastern and America/Vancouver.
My output is below:
2024-07-22 12:02:44.950826-04:00
2024-07-22 09:02:44.951827-07:00
0.0
960.0
0.0
0.0

I printed out the datetime objects from a suggestion and had interesting results!
print(datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0, timezone('America/Vancouver')))
print(datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 15, 11, 0, 0, 0, timezone('US/Eastern')))

Resulted with:
2011-08-15 08:00:00-08:12
2011-08-15 11:00:00-04:56

The time difference is 8:12 and 4:56, the hours makes sense because of daylight saving time but I don't quite understand yet the minutes. Why it isn't on the hour? As in it isn't 8:00 and 5:00 respectively.
Am I doing something wrong? I'm sure there is a proper explanation. Thank you for your help!
Answer found:
It seems that I got confused, since you can input pytz.utc but not a timezone object as an argument. (As seen in this post: stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/8022722) (and in the docs: pythonhosted.org/pytz) It seems that in my case I had to localize the timezone as seen here: stackoverflow.com/a/5946616/8022722 and in the docs as well. I will close my question.

When in doubt, don't ignore the intermediate values. Take a look at the timezones you are passing to the calls to datetime (or rather, the datetime objects resulting from those timezones).

(The point I'm trying to make is, the difference isn't unexpected; the datetime objects used to produce them are.)

@chepner Interesting! I printed out the datetime objects and will update my question to reflect them. I don't yet quite understand why the timezone data is not offset on the hour.

Read the documentation for pytz;  it doesn't mention passing timezone objects as arguments to datetime.

@chepner It seems that I got confused, since you can input pytz.utc but not a timezone object as an argument. (As seen in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7065242/8022722) (and in the docs: https://pythonhosted.org/pytz/)
It seems that in my case I had to localize the timezone as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5946616/8022722
and in the docs as well.
I will close my question.
